# Create a CMakeFiles.txt file for newbies

Tags: c++, cmake, linkage

I have a project with the following structure

```
  /cmake_modules/
    FindSFML.cmake
  /includes/
    car.hpp
    motor.hpp
    tires.hpp
  /sources/
    car.cpp
    motor.cpp
    tires.cpp    
  /main.cpp
  /main.hpp
```

I have the following `CMakeFiles.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project (MYGAME)
set (MYGAME_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (MYGAME_VERSION_MINOR 0)

set (EXECUTABLE_NAME "mygame")

include_directories ("${MYGAME_BINARY_DIR}")
include_directories ("${MYGAME_BINARY_DIR}/includes")
link_directories ("${MYGAME_BINARY_DIR}/sources")

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(SFML 2.0 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)

target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

---

When I try to execute `make` I get this:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mygame.dir/main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable mygame
CMakeFiles/mygame.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `mynamespace::Car::Instance()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `mynamespace::Car::start()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [mygame] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mygame.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the rest of your sources (car.cpp, motor.cpp and tires.cpp) in the build in some way.

You can either add them along with main.cpp in the executable directly:

```
set(MySources sources/car.cpp sources/motor.cpp sources/tires.cpp main.cpp)
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${MySources})
```

or you can make these into a library and link that:

```
set(MyLibSources sources/car.cpp sources/motor.cpp sources/tires.cpp)
add_library(MyLib ${MyLibSources})
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} main.cpp)
...
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} MyLib ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

A couple of other points to note:

You should avoid the use of [`link_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3alink_directories) if possible (its own documentation discourages its use), and it's often helpful to include the headers in the list of files added via `add_executable` or `add_library` since these then show up in IDEs like MS Visual Studio.

Comment: i've removed `link_directories` added `set (MyLib car.cpp .. ..)` and `add_library` but now i get a error Cannot find source file car.cpp

Comment: Sorry - I fixed the examples.  You need to include the "sources" directory in the relative paths to the source files.

Comment: exist some way to include `sources/*.cpp`?

Comment: You can make a list using [`file(GLOB ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:file), although make sure you read the warning about using GLOB or GLOB_RECURSE in the docs.